# If  is measurable and $\leq ()\leq $ for $\in$, and if $\mu(E)<\infty$, then $a\mu(E)\leq \int_E fd\mu \leq b \mu(E)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If  is measurable and  $\leq ()\leq $ for $\in$,  and if $\mu(E)<\infty$, then prove that  $$a\mu(E)\leq \int_E fd\mu \leq b \mu(E).$$

### Work done:

Define two constant functions $g$ and $h$ such that $g(x)=a$ and $h(x)=b$ for all $x$.
Now,

Clearly, $$\int_E g d\mu=a\mu (E)$$
and $$\int_E h d\mu =b\mu(E)$$
Hence,
$$a\mu(E)\leq \int_E f d\mu\leq b\mu(E).$$

I hope this is fine.

But if I wanted to prove this without using the 
$$f\leq g\implies \int f\leq \int g$$
then how to prove this?

Since according to rudin, this result comes after the result whatever i have used in my proof.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you used? How else could you conclude that $a\mu(E)\leq \int f\leq b\mu(E)$?

Comment: @carmichael561 there was a typo. thanks for the notice

Comment: I see. I guess you could try to directly use the definition of $\int f$ as a supremum of integrals of simple functions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the defn:

Let $0\leq s\leq f$ where $s$ is any simple function.

$$\int f d\mu= sup \int s d\mu = sup \sum c_i\mu(E_i)\leq b sup \sum \mu (E_i)=b\mu(E)$$

For the lower bound, consider the function $a$.
Note that $a$ is a simple function.

Now, 
$$a\mu(E)=\sum_{i=1}^n a \mu(E_i)=\int a d\mu \leq sup \int s d\mu =\int f d\mu$$

Hence the proof.